# Jqgrid with MENUTOOLBAR and Listbox on footer toolbar

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I would like to implement a simple JQGrid with **MENU toolbar**  & a Listbox  in 'navButtonAdd' instead of button's  on footer .

Is there some example code Or info in this regard.

with regards
Karthik

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? If you use the Guriddo jqGrid, you can look at demo page [here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/) .You can also look at [this example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/functionality/menubar/index.html)

Comment: Tony, using "http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html" jqgrid 5.5.1  for trials.

a) I need to implement JQUERY MENUBAR "https://jqueryui.com/menu/#icons" 
    on the Footer  or Top bar of the JQgrid  in place of  'navButtonAdd'

b) for some other requirement , need a SELECT menu like 
"https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/"  on the Footer  or Top bar of the JQgrid  in place of  'navButtonAdd'

Is there some sample demo , which i try around 

karthik

Comment: Thx tony looked at the example...

Answer (score 0):

In jqGrid you can define your own custom toolbar with the option:

```
jqGrid({
    // other options here
    toolbar: [true,"both"]
});
```

More you can find for this option [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#options)

Since you know the id of the toolbar(s) you can addd here what you want and attach your own custom events.

[Demo here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/support/stackoverflow/)

Comment: Tony  I wanted to put a listbox on the footer/top bar  ( not part of the colModel ]
Reason :  I want to have functions trigger pdf/xls/csv from the listbox provided and not for any grid options.  thx guys for the help.